# Multiplication Pooling in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there an existing implementation of Multiplication pooling in tensorflow? In TensorFlow documentation, I found only average and max pooling operations.

Can someone suggest me how to do the multiplication pooling?

Comment: You may implement it as a custom layer.

Comment: If you have a Good Use Case which supports this New Feature of `Pooling`, it is recommended to raise a **Feature Request** in Github Tensorflow Repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new/choose, so that Tensorflow Engineers can consider implementing it.